# jQuery Datatables inserting a field value in a coulmn

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a jQuery datatables plugin which does the following,

```
<tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Datee</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
</tr>

 $('#data').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "userlist.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            {
                "mDataProp": null,
                "sDefaultContent": '<a href="delete.php?action=activate&">DEL</a>'
            }
        ]
    } );
```

So what i'm doing here is that i'm getting data using server side processing and adding an additionalm column with link to delete the record.

Now I want id=<> for that particular record to be added at the end of & in a href as

```
a href="delete.php?action=activate&id=<<first column value> .
```

Also i want to convert MySQL date to PHP date for second column.

How can this be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Modify Ricardo's answer as follows:

```
"sDefaultContent": '<a href="delete.php?action=activate&" class="delete">DEL</a>'

$('#data').on('click', 'td .delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
    var href='delete.php?action=activate&id=' + id;
//  $('a.delete', $(this)).attr('href', href);
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

EDIT: You don't need to have the `id` added to the href attribute of the link when the table is rendered in HTML.  The following code will call the `delete.php` script via ajax and will pass the value of `id` to that script.

```
$('#data').on('click', 'td .delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
    $.get("delete.php", {id:id});
});
```

(You will then need to update the displayed datatable as well somehow - there are API functions for this: [Delete a row of a datatable](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)).

UPDATE:  Another option is to do the following:

```
$("a.delete").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
    var href = "delete.php?action=activate&id=" + id;
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've added your solution as shown in the edit but the value of first column is not added after &

Comment: @Ajay: It does not need to be added in the `sDefaultContent` option. When the link is clicked the `window.location=href` will take care of sending the id attribute to the delete script. (You need to use $_GET["id"] in that script.)

Comment: @Ajay: Hmm... the problem is you have two different scripts here.  You use `userlist.php` as your primary ajax script. But you also want to use `delete.php` and also have the datatable update automatically. So actually `window.location` won't work unless `delete.php` outputs the entire table, but then this wont be ajax. I think the thing to do is to incorporate `delete.php` into `userlist.php`.  Then call the delete functions in that script by testing if the delete link has been clicked.  I have to go now but will check again tomorrow.

Comment: what i require is that the third column needs to have a link to another file delete.php which includes the id of the column appended to it. for ex: delete.php?id=<first col value> . I don't require a complex delete function which deletes within the datatable itself.

Comment: @Ajay: Try my edit, which is a jQuery solution where the link does not need to include the id.  But you can also modify the output section of `userlist.php` to add an extra formatted column, if you want to do it that way.

Comment: @Ajay: You can use jQuery to add the id attribute to each link in the 3rd column, as shown in my edit (untested code0.

Comment: Thank you for your help i ended up editing in userlist.php and it was very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [getData](http://datatables.net/ref#fnGetData) or using jquery.
Change the following:

```
"sDefaultContent": '<a href="delete.php?action=activate&">DEL</a>'
```

To:

```
"sDefaultContent": '<a href="delete.php?action=activate&" class="delete">DEL</a>'
```

then use the following code:

```
$('#data').on('click', 'td .delete', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VNP6y/1/)**

Comment: @Ajay: This works - it gets the id from the first column - all you need to do now is to add `window.location='delete.php?action=activate&id=' + id;`

Answer (score 0):

Using version 1.8.2, I was able to return the html using a function for mDataProp. In your case, it would look like:

```
"mDataProp": function (row) { '<a href="delete.php?action=activate&' + row[0] + '">DEL</a>'; }
```