# jQuery Datatables MySQL date to PHP date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datatables

I'm using datatables server side processing to retrieve all values for my table. One column renders registration dates of users which is in MySQL date format. Can it be converted to PHP date format while displaying.

```
$('#data').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "userlist.php",
} );
```

Thanks.

Working Solution :

Added this to server-side but no effect,

```
while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)) {
$row = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
    if ($aColumns[$i] == "version") {
        /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
        $row[] = ($aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == "0") ? '-' : $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
    } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == "date") {
        /* Special output formatting for 'date' column */
        $date = new DateTime($aRow["date"]);
        $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        $row[] = date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
    } elseif ($aColumns[$i] != ' ') {
        /* General output */
        $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
    } 
}
$output['aaData'][] = $row;
```

}

One of my mysql columns has the name 'date'.

Comment: What do you mean by 'PHP date format'? I assume that by 'MySQL date format' you mean 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: I mean to convert YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YY etc

Comment: Wrong order of `if else` statements - last two should be swopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `userlist.php` just use PHP `date('d-m-Y', $timestamp)` or whatever to reformat the dates as you wish before sending output from the script.

RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

This code is untested, but the principle is as follows:

You would have a date column in your SQL table, let's say it's called 'date'. Therefore [in the example script](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html):

```
$aColumns = array('date', etc.);
```

At bottom of script, in 'output' section, you see this:

```
if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
{
    /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
    $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
}
/* insert this date formatting statement here */
elseif ( $aColumns[$i] == "date" ) {
    /* Special output formatting for 'date' column */
    $date = new DateTime($aRow["date"]);
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $row[] = date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
}
```

If you need to do sorting on the date column, it is possible that you might need to use a date sorting plugin, because datatables don't provide default sorting for all date formats.

Comment: In the serverside userlist.php where should i include it. Example code : http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: @Ajay: I have added a suggestion on how to do this for the example script.

Comment: I've added the code to server-side but there is no effect in the output. Check my edit.

Comment: @Ajay: You need to add the statement like I show in my edited post - BEFORE the 'general output' elseif is used.

Comment: Can you help with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667685/jquery-datatables-inserting-a-field-value-in-a-coulmn

Comment: @Ajay:I have made a quick suggestion, hope it helps.